# Find minimal elements of set of vectors

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a set of vectors, and I need to write algorithm in java, to find minimal elements of this set. Problem is, that there are elements which are incomparable. E.g. minset{(1,4,6),(3,2,5),(2,3,4),(5,4,6)} = {(1,4,6),(3,2,5),(2,3,4)}. For set of minimal element "minset" following holds: every vector from the original set is either in "minset" or >= than some vector in the new set in every component. E.g. minset{(2,3,4),(2,3,5)} = {(2,3,4)}. I've already have algorithm for this, but I think it can be done with better computional complexity. My algorithm takes one element, mark it as minimal, then take other element, compare them, if there are incomparable, mark both as minimal, if second is smaller then mark only it as minimal etc... Is it possible to use mergesort or heapsort to optimize this algorithm? Thank for all responses.

Comment: What measure do you use to compare vectors?

Comment: What elements are considered "incomparable"? I'm not understanding why minset{(1,4,6),(3,2,5),(2,3,4),(5,4,6)} = {(1,4,6),(3,2,5),(2,3,4)}. Can you define the problem more clearly?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. You want to get a subset of vectors such that every vector in the original set is either in the new set or greater than some vector in the new set in every component. I'll think about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found solution for my problem in article http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2758&context=compsci, where is algorithm for finding maximal elements of set of vectors which is similar problem. It works in much more better computional complexity that my firts intuitive algorithm.

Comment: This is a good start for a useful answer, but a link to a paper when the question asked for an algorithm isn't helpful to future readers of the answer (especially when the link dies). Can you include the source code you wrote after reading the answer or a short description of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I created a [runnable example](http://ideone.com/PtDslH). It uses Java's builtin `Arrays.sort()` and a `Comparator` which compares two vectors of size `L`. You could do something similar using `Collections.sort()` if you prefer to use `List` data structures over arrays.

From the [Java API Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

```
This algorithm offers guaranteed n*log(n) performance.
```

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        final int L = 3;

        int[][] vectors = {
            {1, 4, 6},
            {3, 2, 5},
            {2, 3, 4},
            {5, 4, 6},
            {7, 7, 7},
            {3, 3, 5},
            {8, 8, 8},
        };

        Comparator<int[]> cmp = new Comparator<int[]>() {
            public int compare(int[] v1, int[] v2) {
                int cmp0 = Integer.signum(v1[0] - v2[0]);
                for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
                int cmp1 = Integer.signum(v1[i] - v2[i]);
                    if (cmp1 != 0) {
                        if (cmp1 != cmp0) {
                            return 0;
                        }
                        cmp0 = cmp1;
                    }
                }
                return cmp0;
            }
        };

        Arrays.sort(vectors, cmp);

        System.out.println("minset:");
        int i = 0;
        int[] vPref = vectors[0];
        while (cmp.compare(vectors[i], vPref) == 0) {
            for (int x : vectors[i]){
                System.out.print(x + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            vPref = vectors[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you estimate the complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` is `n*log(n)`.

Comment: I am sorry, but i realized, that this algoritm doesnt do what I need, for the set you use, it returns set which obtains (3, 2, 5) and (3, 3, 5). That is incorect, because  (3, 2, 5) <= (3, 3, 5)

Comment: You mean (3, 2, 5) < (3, 3, 5) ? That depends on how you define inequality... So apparently you want that [v_i < w_i] for any i -> [v < w], v and w being vectors. I updated the algorithm to match that definition, check it out!

Comment: Yes, that is what I need, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: i tied algoritm for this set:{
            {9, 4, 6},
            {9, 2, 5},
            {9, 3, 4},
            {9, 4, 6},
            {9, 7, 7},
            {8, 6, 6},
            {8, 7, 7},
        }; 
and the result minset:{
(9, 4, 6), 
(9, 2, 5), 
(9, 3, 4), 
(9, 4, 6), 
(8, 6, 6), 
(8, 7, 7)}
is incorect

Comment: Your comparator does not define a total order and therefore invalid to use for sorting.

Answer (score -1):

Pseudocode:

```
foreach inputVector in vectors
    foreach minVector in minSet
        if (all components of inputVector <= components of minVector
            delete minVector
        elseif (all components of inputVector >= components of minVector)       
            skip to next inputVector
    if inputVector made it through the entire minSet, then add it to minSet
```

Comment: I have the same pseudocode, but I am trying to find out if its possible to find minset with better computional complexity